# second order non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the second order differential equation:

$ y'' - 9 y^2 = 0$ with $y(0) = y'(0) = 0 ?$

My attempt is the following: [image]

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have an autonomous equation or system, if written as first order system, $$y'=v, ~~ v'=9y^2,$$ that starts in an equilibrium position $y(0)=0$ with zero velocity $v(0)=0$. Thus the constant function with the equilibrium as value $y(t)\equiv0$ is a solution.

As the equation or right side of the system is continuously differentiable, it is also locally Lipschitz, enforcing uniqueness of the solution. Thus there is no other solution than $$y(t)=0~~~\forall t\in\Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''=9y^2$$
Multiply by $2y'$ on both sides, to get
$$2y'y''=18y^2y' \implies \frac{d(y')^2}{dx}=18y^2 \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Integrate both sides w.r.t. $x$ to get
$$\int d(y'^2)= \int 18y^2 dy \implies y'^2=A+6y^3 \implies A=0$$
$$\implies y'=\pm \sqrt{6y^3} \implies \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{6y^3} } dy=\pm \int dx.$$
$$\implies -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=\pm x+B$$
the condition $y(0)=0$ is not compactible to give a finite solution.

OP's approach is correct.

Comment: OP's approach is correct but $y(0)=0=y'(0)$ does not lead to a finite solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to switch variable and write
$$\frac {x''}{[x']^3}+9y^2=0$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives
$$\frac {p'}{[p]^3}+9y^2=0\implies p=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6 y^3- c_1}}$$ The condition $y'(0)=0$ makes $c_1=$ and
$$p=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6 y^3}}$$ leads to @Z Ahmed's answer .